# Google App Script to export and replace csv files

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script

I currently have a google spreadsheet that will create a csv file and save it on my google drive when the trigger goes off. What I can't figure out is how to delete the existing csv file before creating a new csv file. When it saves the new version, it simply makes another copy. I need to overwrite the previous file (or delete the old one then export/write the new version.)

Here is the script to create the csv file:

```
function saveAsCSV() {
  // Prompts the user for the file name
  var fileName = ("myCSVFile");
  // Check that the file name entered wasn't empty
  if (fileName.length !== 0) {
    // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
    fileName = fileName + ".csv";
    // Convert the range data to CSV format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // Create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the CSV data
    DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a CSV file name.");
  }
}
```

How can I overwrite the csv file every time the script trigger goes off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete/overwrite CSV file using google apps script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965442/how-to-delete-overwrite-csv-file-using-google-apps-script)

Comment: I tried working with that solution and could not get it to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the file before writing the new one using `file.setTrashed(true)`. See the lead example in the [File Class documentation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

Comment: I was able to find a solution in the link you provided. The file gets deleted and a new one takes its place. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can either delete the file first, using `File.setTrashed(true);`, or you can simply change the contents of the file, using `File.setContent(csvFile);`

Comment: For changing the content of the file do I replace this: "DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile);" with your solution: "File.setContent(csvFile);"?

Comment: Yes, except that you would get the `File` *instance*, not the singleton like `DriveApp`. For instance, `var f = DriveApp.getFile(id); f.setContent(csv);`